# Unity: How to receive input events on a RectTransform that does not contain any image/text/...?

Tags: unity, gui

In Unity 2018.3: Imagine a `GameObject` with only a `RectTransform` component and a custom script attached to it - otherwise completely empty. Is there a way to receive input events (like `IPointerClickHandler.OnPointerClick`) without adding any graphical GUI components like text/image/rawimage/etc. ?

In other words: Is there a component or superclass available to receive input events without adding an unused graphical component?

Any clarifications are welcome,
Thank you.

Comment: Did you try [this approach](http://answers.unity.com/answers/1157876/view.html)?

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Feel free to write up an answer if you've solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@DMGregory pointed out, an elegant solution](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1091618/ui-panel-without-image-component-as-raycast-target.html?childToView=1157876#answer-1157876) is to inherit a script from Graphics class, which works just perfect.